# Migrate CakePHP database from XAMPP to MAMP

Tags: cakephp, xampp, mamp

I'm new to CakePHP and SQL in general. I'm trying to migrate a database on my Windows laptop to my Macbook and I have no idea where to start. What do I need to do?

Comment: Download phpmyadmin. You can export and imoprt databases from there.

Comment: Try to use Phpmyadmin and export your db as a text file. Phpmyadmin should be part of your XAMPP distribution. I guess there is a similar tool under MAMP (maybe the same) to import your DB.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use phpmyadmin as some people in the comments suggest but instead the proper tools for that task. Using phpmyadmin is a bad idea because there can be encoding issues with the file it will generate and if the db is large it can run out of memory while im/exporting.

Backup:

`mysqldump -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] > dumpfilename.sql`

Restore:

`mysql -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] < dumpfilename.sql`

[Here is a complete article about that.](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/backup-and-restore-mysql-database-using-mysqldump/)